# Elasticsearch error when creating index

Tags: elasticsearch

I am getting the following error when trying to create an index:

```
{"error":"IndexCreationException[[myindex] failed to create index]; nested: NoClassDefFoundError[Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.index.codec.postingsformat.PostingFormats]; ","status":500}
```

When I do

```
curl http://localhost:9200
```

I get:

```
{
"ok" : true,
"status" : 200,
"name" : "Shamrock",
"version" : {
    "number" : "0.90.5",
    "build_hash" : "c8714e8e0620b62638f660f6144831792b9dedee",
    "build_timestamp" : "2013-09-17T12:50:20Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.4"
},
"tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

When I do

```
java -version
```

I get

```
java version "1.7.0_13"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_13-b20)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

When I do

```
echo "$JAVA_HOME"
```

I get

```
/usr/local/jdk
```

Here is the elasticsearch.log

```
[2013-09-19 22:27:04,637][INFO ][node                     ] [Iron Lad] {0.90.0.Beta1}[15738]: initializing ...
[2013-09-19 22:27:04,646][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Iron Lad] loaded [], sites []
[2013-09-19 22:27:07,170][INFO ][node                     ] [Iron Lad] {0.90.0.Beta1}[15738]: initialized
[2013-09-19 22:27:07,170][INFO ][node                     ] [Iron Lad] {0.90.0.Beta1}[15738]: starting ...
[2013-09-19 22:27:07,333][INFO ][transport                ] [Iron Lad] bound_address {inet[/0.0.0.0:9301]}, publish_address {inet[/66.66.66.66:9301]}
[2013-09-19 22:27:10,407][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Iron Lad] new_master [Iron Lad][Nl9geV2WQICQRPCjZbGg5w][inet[/66.66.66.66:9301]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2013-09-19 22:27:10,434][INFO ][discovery                ] [Iron Lad] elasticsearch/Nl9geV2WQICQRPCjZbGg5w
[2013-09-19 22:27:10,495][INFO ][http                     ] [Iron Lad] bound_address {inet[/0.0.0.0:9201]}, publish_address {inet[/66.66.66.66:9201]}
[2013-09-19 22:27:10,495][INFO ][node                     ] [Iron Lad] {0.90.0.Beta1}[15738]: started
[2013-09-19 22:27:10,501][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Iron Lad] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
[2013-09-19 22:29:32,668][INFO ][node                     ] [Iron Lad] {0.90.0.Beta1}[15738]: stopping ...
[2013-09-19 22:29:32,703][INFO ][node                     ] [Iron Lad] {0.90.0.Beta1}[15738]: stopped
[2013-09-19 22:29:32,704][INFO ][node                     ] [Iron Lad] {0.90.0.Beta1}[15738]: closing ...
[2013-09-19 22:29:32,733][INFO ][node                     ] [Iron Lad] {0.90.0.Beta1}[15738]: closed
[2013-09-19 22:29:34,985][INFO ][node                     ] [Worthington, Warren III] {0.90.0.Beta1}[16047]: initializing ...
[2013-09-19 22:29:34,991][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Worthington, Warren III] loaded [], sites []
[2013-09-19 22:29:37,492][INFO ][node                     ] [Worthington, Warren III] {0.90.0.Beta1}[16047]: initialized
[2013-09-19 22:29:37,492][INFO ][node                     ] [Worthington, Warren III] {0.90.0.Beta1}[16047]: starting ...
[2013-09-19 22:29:37,576][INFO ][transport                ] [Worthington, Warren III] bound_address {inet[/0.0.0.0:9301]}, publish_address {inet[/66.66.66.66:9301]}
[2013-09-19 22:29:40,613][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Worthington, Warren III] new_master [Worthington, Warren III][-VnBhd4JTKe3Vg0PGqGKcg][inet[/66.66.66.66:9301]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2013-09-19 22:29:40,655][INFO ][discovery                ] [Worthington, Warren III] elasticsearch/-VnBhd4JTKe3Vg0PGqGKcg
[2013-09-19 22:29:40,717][INFO ][http                     ] [Worthington, Warren III] bound_address {inet[/0.0.0.0:9201]}, publish_address {inet[/66.66.66.66:9201]}
[2013-09-19 22:29:40,717][INFO ][node                     ] [Worthington, Warren III] {0.90.0.Beta1}[16047]: started
[2013-09-19 22:29:40,721][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Worthington, Warren III] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
```

Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you setup elasticsearch? just downloaded and run it?

Comment: Thats one thing I'm not sure of just yet as it was installed by my hosting provider.

Comment: Did you check `/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log`? Anything in there?

Comment: I just found out where it was installed and have updated my original post with the elasticsearch.log. I adjusted my ip to 66.66.66.66 for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found there were multiple elastic search nodes running. I ended up stopping all of them and then started one up using /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start.

Keep in mind you need to install the init.d script by following the instructions at:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/setup/installation/